# Restoring an item from an SQL Database in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, detailsview, detailview

I'm currently learning `ASP.Net` and I was wondering how you can `restore an item` that was deleted from an `SQL Data source`. 
The item was deleted through a `Details View` using the `"Enable Deleting"` option, so I was testing each of the `buttons` and this happened.
I understand that I can simply recover the same `untouched database file`, and replace it with the current one I'm using.
 
However, I'd like to know if `restoring` the item is possible through other means, like creating a button which will restore the `Database Item from deletion`.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as "standard SQL" is concerned, once you do an SQL `DELETE` on a row, it's gone for good.

If you need "undelete" functionality in your system, you could instead just add a "deleted" column to the database, and set that instead of deleting. That has the major downside that all your SQL needs to take that column into account, so that rows with the delete column set are not returned. Quite a lot of work, and does not sound like what you're looking for in this case.

In certain RDBMS' (SQL server comes to mind), there are ways to recover deleted rows from the transaction log, but that does not sound like what you're looking for either, and it's quite an advanced topic.

Comment: I see, yeah I'm not aiming at anything too advanced, but thanks for your answer!